How to minify CSS isolation in Blazor?
I followed the tutorial in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-8.0#additional-resources
And now the CSS isolation works well.
I have a problem that the CSS isolation style(just like this blow) is not minified.
<link href="{ASSEMBLY NAME}.styles.css" rel="stylesheet">

I've thought about minimizing it using a tool like BuildBundlerMinifier. However, it seems it is not a static file and it is generated dynamically so I can't use a third-party tool to minimize it.
Is there any way that I can minimize it to make page access faster?
Thank you.

To my knowledge, there is no built-in support for achieving css isolation and minification at the same time, but it might be possible to find a workaround. You can try build events for this purpose, which would involve specifying a post build event and executing a command that will minify the specified file. Since this command will be executed after the build, the bundled css file from css isolation should be there.
The tool I will recommend is clean-css-cli (https://www.npmjs.com/package/clean-css-cli), however you can use any library that will work via commands.
Install node.js (which will come with NPM), then install the library globally using NPM with this command:
npm install -g clean-css-cli

Then, add the post build event into your .csproj file (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-specify-build-events-csharp?view=vs-2022 for additional info on build events)
<Target Name="MinifyCSS" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent">
    <Exec Command="cleancss -o $(ProjectDir)\bin\Release\net7.0\publish\wwwroot\css\style.min.css $(ProjectDir)\bin\Release\net7.0\publish\wwwroot\css\style.css" />
</Target>

I will admit, this is a shot in the dark and I am currently not available to test this, but let me know if it works. You should review the path I specified. Keep in mind that you really don't want to have minification in place during development (it will make debugging painful for no reason).

Well, it seems that’s all we can do for the time being.
